# ¿Se puede trabajar con los sockets en PHP usando el paradigma POO?

Tags: php, java, poo, socket, redes

Estoy iniciando en este tema y para practicar un poco vi este código cliente en internet que se conecta a un servidor java y le manda un mensaje, el código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$host = "127.0.0.1"; 
$port = 9000; 
$message = "Este mensaje te lo envio desde el cliente saludos"."\n"; 

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("No se pudo crear el socket\n");

$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("No se pudo conectar con el servidor\n"); 

socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("No se pudo enviar datos al servidor\n"); 

$Value = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("No se pudo leer la respuesta del servidor\n"); 
echo "El servidor dice :<br>".$Value; 
socket_close($socket); 

?>
```

El código anterior lo pase al paradigma orientado a objetos, creando una clase atributos y métodos, el siguiente es el resultado

```
<?php
/**
 * 
 */
class Cliente 
{
    private $Socket;
    private $host="127.0.0.1";
    private $conectar;
    private $Request;


    public function CreateSocket(){
        try {

            $this->Socket=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
            $this->conectar=socket_connect($this->Socket, "127.0.0.1",9000);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error al crear el Socket";
        }
    }

    public function WriteMessage($message){
        socket_write($this->Socket, $message, strlen($message));
    }

    public function ReadMessage(){
        if (socket_read($this->Socket,1024)==false) {
            echo "No se puede leer el mensaje";
        };
        socket_close($this->Socket);
    }
}
```

Cuando lo corro el se queda "cargando" hasta que pasa mucho tiempo y PHP termina la ejecución, es como si se quedara en bucle se me hace algo extraño ya que lo único que estoy haciendo es meter en funciones/métodos las instrucciones para crear conectar escribir y leer Socket.

Revisando un poco me doy cuenta que el único método que falla es de "ReadMessage", ya que si no lo ejecuto todo funciona correctamente.